# How can I find the diameter of a wire if I have the length and resistance? I cannot use measuring tool because wire is thinner than 0.1 mm

Tags: resistance, measurement, wire, gauge

As the title suggests; I am trying to calculate the diameter of a wire given its length and resistance.

Specifications:

- Length: 30.4 cm
- Resistance: 17 Ω

Comment: Is it copper? At 17 ohm for 30.4 cm, it needs to be incredibly thin if copper, or made from some other material. Have you looked up the resistivity for the conductor in question and tried to calculate it? What result did you come up with?

Comment: You need to know the material. The resistivity of 'resistance wire' (nichrome, constantan, Eureka, others) covers an order of magnitude, and they are very different to copper. Different grades of carbon steel, stainless steel, similarly vary wildly. You need a micrometer to measure the diameter. Trying to estimate it for an unknown material is like trying to weigh somebody by measuring the length of their shoe, other variables are too significant.

Comment: That would be a horribly poor wire to use as conductor no matter the material...

Comment: I agree with @Lundin, don't use someone's shoe as conductor!

Comment: @Lundin It's roughly the resistance of a foot of 1mil ⌀ gold or aluminum bonding wire.

Answer (score 4):

If you know for sure the resistivity of the whatever material the wires is made of and know it to be round you can use the formula for area of a circle (which would be the cross-sectional area of a round wire) and the length together with the resistivity and resistance to find the diameter.

If it's a real problem rather than homework you can just use a micrometer. For example, my Mitutoyo micrometer reads to a resolution of 0.001mm, and with care is repeatable to that. If the wire is a very soft material it might be deformed by the micrometer anvils though.

There are also optical methods of measuring small dimensions, sometimes against a graticule, or you could compare it under a microscope against a reference (the smallest gauge pin I have in my set is 0.1mm⌀ - I almost thought the capsule was empty when I opened it).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this online calculator. Annealed copper with a length of 30.4 cm and a resistance of 17 ohms shows a diameter of 0.01973 mm. https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance
Of course, if it is school work, you should also understand the principles involved.